# Gitlab runner not executing bash script

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup CI with gitlab and AWS. I have setup gitlab-runner properly on the aws instance running ubuntu 16.04.

But I am getting this error while deploying.

```
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/m4kamran/project-test'...
Checking out ea183ff7 as production...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ pip install docker-compose
/bin/sh: eval: line 72: pip: not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error contains your problem:

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 72: pip: not found
```

You do not have `pip` installed, if this is a container you should try a python image as pip will already be available.

Answer (score 0):

You use image without installed pip, I think. Try to make `apt install python-pip` (depends on your image OS).